# Circle boundary problem?

Tags: circles

How many circles could exit having diameter 25.4mm and and distance from each other 5mm, on a big circle boundary (circumference) having diameter 1472mm ?

Comment: Do you mean that their centres are on the great circle?

Comment: I would also assume that any two circles are supposed to have **at least** distance $5\text{mm}$ from one another, otherwise it might be unclear how five "consecutive" circles $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5$ would arrange, seeing as $C_2$ and $C_4$ are very likely to be further apart than $C_2$ and $C_3$.

Comment: @Gae.S. yes man thier centers are on big circle !

Comment: Can Anyone help ?